# Show, for each field, how many items has each field DjangoREST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a Django project, coding some API calls where people can reserve a parking place.
I have a database, and I want to display how many reservations has each user.

I know this can be done easily on SQL, but I can't find the way to do this on Python.
I've already tried to do what the documentation says: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet
but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You can get the count using <Model>.objects.filter(<field>=<value>).count()

Comment: May you post the code you tried? As @Mihai said you can filter the reservations by a specific user and then count them with the `count` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import Count:

```
from django.db.models import Count
```

Then try to do something like that:

```
return X.objects.values('xx').annotate(xx=Count('xx')).filter(xx__gte = whatever you want).count()
```

Should work